# Can I use Google Maps instead of Microsoft Maps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-maps

In Windows 10, I like the way you can click on an address in, say, the People app and it'll load a map of where they live.

Unfortunately I'd rather that it uses Google Maps instead of Microsoft's own (which failed to find the first address I tried it with).

I had a dig in the settings and it suggests that Microsoft Maps look out for four protocols:

[image]

Is there any way I can change these so that they open Google Maps (in a browser is fine) instead?

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find a google maps app in the Microsoft app store, so you may have to just use the website version. You can also download Maps App + from Microsoft app store which uses google maps. From there you will have to set your default maps app to Maps App +.